# Draw a random value from a given distribution

Tags: python, numpy, random, poisson

I have an `array` of values which I have generated starting from an observed value `y1`, and assuming that this value has a [poissonian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Definition) distribution:

```
array = np.random.poisson(np.real(y1), 10000)
```

What if I want to extract a random value from `array`, which is poissonian distributed, and hence has a "most probable value" that peaks at `y1`? How can I do that? Does it work by simple random extraction, or does it need something else to be specified?

EDIT: trying to be more specific. I have an array whose elements are Poisson distributed. If I want to randomly extract an element from that array, should I tell to the method about the array distribution, or it is not necessary?
I hope this will clarify a bit.

Comment: Regardless of the data in the array, if you want to generate a random index from which to get a value from the array, you would just use `random.randint(0, arraySize)`

Comment: Your question is a bit difficult to interpret... As an example, by my interpretation, if you had the distribution [.25, .75], you would like your random choices to be something like [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1...], ie, there are roughly 3x as many 1s as 0s? Or, by Alex's and mickey's interpretation, you would have as many 1s as 0s? So which do you want (or something else)?

Comment: @tom10, sorry, I do not understand your question. I mean, in poissonian distribution, there is a more likely value (the peak), and less probable values (the tails). When the method goes to randomly chose from the poissonian distributed array, does it need to know about the distribution, or this is not necessary since the distribution is already defined within the array?

Comment: The word "randomly" is not enough. As you know, random numbers can have distributions.  Do you want to select each element with equal probability or based on this distribution (ie, with the probability of the value in the distribution).  So, again, if your distribution were [.25, .75], would you like to select .25 as often as .75, or would you like to select .75 more often because it's the more probable value.

Comment: @tom10, yes, I want that the random choice selects more often the more probable value, of course. But, my doubt was: if the more probable value is also the more frequent, does the module need to know about the distribution? I.e., if we have [.25, .75, .75, .75], it comes naturally that the more probable value will be extracted more often...

Comment: I see. `np.random.poission` returns samples from the distribution and you want to select randomly from those samples. Yes, then you can just select randomly. But why? Then you're just resammpling a sample, and introducing errors from your finite sample size. You can also just step along the array and create a new one if you need more samples.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, I have to resample, to simulate data. Does it not make sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68895/discussion-between-tom10-and-py-ser).

Answer (score 1):

Just

```
import random
randval = random.choice(array)
```

should work fine for you.  Once `array` is generated, in order to pick one at random of its items it does not matter any more by what process or according to what distribution `array` was populated in the first place.